# how to save figure of gui plot which will run on a computer that does not have matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have made a Gui program that I compile to EXE application which lots csv file into graph data. I buit a save button but I do not know how save figure with different name each time cause (savefig anduisave both uses matlab program). I am posting my code below if anyoff you guys figure out how to save gui figue into image  or anything that does require matlab to open. Last function is the callback function for save button.

```
function ma_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% i tried uisave but not possible to run computer without matlab cause mcr
% does not run uisave
% i tried copyopbj but since i did not put a name on my figure it did not
% work
%savefig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to save a kind of image from your figure, then the best option which supports many aspects, is using `print` function.

I have already done this in a compiled app and it works perfect. Using print function you can set different file type(vector formats like *.svg are also supported), resolution(dpi), and so many others.

Although you can use `print` function directly on the figure, but I found that the best way (More Customization like removing or adding some objects and changing many options) is to follow this steps:

1. Create another figure with `Visible='on'` but a position that is out of screen with the same width and height of Main Figure. 
   **normalized position = [-1, -1, ?, ?]**. (Create this figure in start up and don't destroy it until your app exits, let call it `Print Figure`).
2. Copy your figure content (or the parts you are interested in) using `copyobj` to that figure (you may need to set Parent property of some key objects like panels to this new figure). They would look exactly as they look in the main figure, because they have the same properties. you can add or remove some objects in this step.
3. Change aspect ratio of "Print Figure" for a better output.
4. Print this figure with all options (file format, dpi, ...) you need. in my own GUI i allowed the user to change this settings with an input dialog.

In my app i used functions like `winopen` to show the output, and output directory to the user, when the print task was done. Print process takes some time, specially if dpi is huge, so it is also a good idea to inactivate buttons and show wait cursor.

**Update:**

a simple usage would be:

```
print(MainFigure, 'myFileName', '-dpng', '-r300')
```

Comment: @ eulerleibniz , hi this my first time GUI, I am not that of an expert on this. is there any easy way to do it. if I just want to save gui with different like the Microsoft word document being save and later not be pulled out

Comment: dear @ParthaDey, Your comment is not clear. what you mean different like the Microsoft word document? if you want to save as a .fig file, then that can't be done, because compiled app are meant to be used for computers without MATLAB installed. yet you can save figure object to a .mat file and load it later.

Comment: @ eulerleibniz   cannot I use uiputfile and print the figure as.jpg format . How ever, I do not know what variable to print out with print function from the code. Would you be able to tell me what is the variable to print out. is it handles.axes1 which  is the Gui plot.

Comment: is not working . would you able to tell me what to put instead of  MainFigure when I will use  print function in my code.

Comment: @ParthaDey. MainFigure is name of the figure you created. in your code after plot command use `MainFigure = gcf` to get handle of the figure like, and then use it for printing.